# Importing seaborn causes code to run twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I'm running seaborn on Python 3.6.5 (32-bit), Windows 10. So long as I import seaborn, it causes my code in shell to run twice.

**My code:**

```
import seaborn

print('Load success!')

for x in range(5):
    print(x)
```

> Load success!
>   0
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   Load success!
>   0
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4

When commenting out or removing the import of seaborn it goes back to normal.

```
#import seaborn

print('Load success!')

for x in range(5):
    print(x)
```

> Load success!
>   0
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4

I can't recreate this bug with any other module and I've restarted my computer already.

My question is how can I fix this bug, has this happened to anyone else, and where can I file a bug report with seaborn?

Comment: I can't recreate this. Works as expected while importing seaborn. Maybe try uninstalling seaborn and installing seaborn with `pip`.

Comment: what is the name of your source file? or are you typing it on shell line by line?

Comment: @NipunSampath the name of the .py file my module is in?

Comment: yes, what is the name you gave?

Comment: It is called seadata.py, I have tried changing the name and that does not change the outcome (such as asdf.py)

Answer (score 1):

Problem found: Within the same file directory I had a test file called seaborn.py, which caused the code to run twice. After deleting the seaborn.py file, the problem no longer occurred.

Comment: yeah, that was why I asked for the file name :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to put the reason why it happened here. Python always check your root folder first before importing modules from PYTHONPATH. So as you had a **seaborn.py** file in your root directory(location of the script file you ran) python imported that one instead of the seaborn module in the PYTHONPATH. The seaborn.py was also having the same code, so it seemed as the code ran twice. This will also happen if you tried to import the **seaborn.py** while inside the **seaborn.py** file itself.